# anaconda: the solving environment keeps failing and freezing

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm a beginner at all this code stuff so recently I have been trying to get this hole excel and python thing working using visual studio code and anaconda but without fail sup lexes me into the moon, I mean just doesn't work searching around to find a way to fix but nothing its been annoying and I have been at it for months now so whenever I try to get it to work it doesn't I'm using this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/data-science-tutorial to help work it but nothing in the end if someone could tell me the problem or an alternative I would appreciate it here is an image to accompany it
[basically I open the anaconda prompt and enter the command that was given to me by the guide but it just didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M5pZ.png)

Comment: Please don't post important parts of your question as screen dumps and/or external links.  Think about what you'd have if those links stopped working.  If your question could not then be understood, you should move the necessary information into your question itself.  In this case, the first link in your question is probably ok, but for the second one, you should copy the text from your screen and paste it into your question rather than providing a screenshot.

Comment: As to your question...I'm not a Conda user (I use regular cython), but the error message you're getting seems to be saying something pretty obvious.  It's saying that Tensorflow isn't available in the standard Conda package channels.  I took a look at the Tensorflow docs for Conda, and it seems that maybe there are some extra steps you have to go through to install Tensorflow via Conda.  Maybe someone more knowledgable of Conda will come along and can give you better help.  In the meantime, check this out: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow. Good luck!

Comment: i have already tried that and the same thing keeps happining

Comment: (base) C:\Users\user>conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Comment: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow

Current channels:

  - htt://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-32
  - htt://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
  - htt://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
  - htt://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - htt://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
  - htt://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - htt://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
  - htt://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch